# Package <blah> does not exist error - NetBeans 6.8 & Windows 7

Tags: java, netbeans, windows-7, package

I'm using NetBeans 6.8 on Windows 7. I upgraded from WinXP and NetBeans 6.7. Now my existing java web app project is no longer able to import/find the packages I've developed - I receive a 'Package ,blah. does not exist' and yet the packages do exist, worked fine in NetBeans 6.7 and the project still compiles and runs OK.

I've tried changing the Java Platform/JDK from 1.6.0_10 back to JDK 1.5.0_22 but I still receive errors package  does not exist.

All other 'standard' libraries and packages are able to be imported and used OK ... eg Struts, Hibernate

Comment: You may want to replace <blah> with an actual package name, so we have a better idea of what we are trying to help you with...

Comment: you may want to upgrade to jdk 6 update 18... though I doubt that will have an effect in this particular situation.

Comment: I have developed the packages, they are part of my Struts app - the names are com.dmeasy.utils, com.dmeasy.action, com.dmeasy.persistence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create a new empty web application, check the existing project out from SVN, regenerate the build-impl.xml & configure the library references.

All is now importing and referencing OK

I do not have an explanation as to why the problem occurred the first time this project was created

Comment: This solution failed after 3-4 hrs. I've now uninstalled NetBeans and have downloaded NetBeans 6.9m1, opening the existing project worked ok and so far 24 hrs later all imports are functioning still

Comment: Still having the same problem in 8.0 and no solution found on the web helps (clearing cache etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem many times by clearing the NetBeans cache.

1) Close NetBeans

2) Go to "C:\Users\.netbeans\6.8\var\cache

3) Delete everything that is in this directory

4) Open NetBeans and wait for it to re-scan your projects

At this time, this has fixed my problem.  I do need to do this every once and a while, but if I don't change anything in the project's structure, the issue does not come back, and I can develop in peace!

Hope it helps someone in need.

Comment: Has the location changed in Netbeans 8.02?  I have this problem, but I don't have a .netbeans directory in my Users directory.  I only have .nbi, .nbprofiler, and .netbeans-derby.

Comment: It is possible that the location has changed.  Do you have a similar path under the ".netbeans-derby" folder?  If so try it in that folder!

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch - Have you tried:
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\NetBeans?

Comment: Thank you so much! 6 years later, still relevant. For those using 8.2, go to your Program Files -> NetBeans 8.2 -> Search 'cache,' copy the folder to the desktop as a backup and delete everything in the folder, not the folder, but what's inside. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Netbeans 7.0.1. Suddenly after some work I could not compile my project anymore, because a major package "does not exit" anymore. All my projects settings (build properties, project properties, dependencies ) seemed ok for me.

The only (bad) solution I could find is, to copy the relevant module to a new name, remove the old and re-create the module again by copy/paste of packages. Now it works again.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the error when I had the same jar installed twice - as compile library and as a test library.

As the result, many of packages became invisible.

After removing the jar from compile libraries everything become visible.

Answer (score 0):

In the project Properties, under "Libraries", "Compile" tab. Do an "Add jar/folder" of the "src" directory if it's a regular Java project.  If it's JSF, use "src/java" instead.

Answer (score -2):

just change s by S in System.out., is simple but i think is your problem